# magento order view information is blank page

Tags: magento-1.7

[image]
when I click order view in admin panel, the information is blank page.Anyone can help me out?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: We need more details. What has changed recently in your installation? Are you getting any errors? More information please.

Comment: Some product sku has modified, so when customer bought the products, I login in admin panel, click order view, I can't get any information about customer order.It just show # url.

Comment: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, boolean given, called in /home/cosplay2/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml on line 38 and defined  in /home/cosplay2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 139

Comment: Has your /home/cosplay2/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/i‌​tems/column/name.phtml  been modified?

Comment: No, I don't modify the file so far.I don't know how to solve the issue.I hope you can help me? I'm grateful to you.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, after checking the error log I noticed a PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '['..... so check /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php line 121. Near:

```
public function escapeHtmlWithLinks($data, $allowedTags = null)
{
    if (!empty($data) && is_array($allowedTags) && in_array('a', $allowedTags)) {
        $links = [];
```

Change $links = []; to $links = array();

That did it for me,
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I found It :D
From there:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98236/35766

Qoute:
The use of [] instead of array() in this patch makes it backward incompatible with PHP < 5.4 (see known issues below)

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98237/2380

BUG IN CORE:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/1266

So @Daniel Adarve have right

So you have PHP < 5.4 or missing admin template.
Check PHP version and links above.
Cheers! :)