# Blank admin page after installing SUPEE7405

Tags: patches, supee-7405

I'm new to Magento and installed today the **SUPEE7405** patch without SSH.
Now I have a blank admin page and cant get it back running. I cleared `var/session` and `var/cache`. I checked the `includes/config.php` that the compiler is disabled. I activated the error message and received

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Helper_UnserializeArray' not found in app/Mage.php on line 547

Has anybody got a idea to solve the problem.

Comment: Which version of Magento are you running ? Is the following file present on your system app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php ?

Comment: I'm using Version 1.9.2.1. No, no UnserializeArray.php in the folder

Comment: The app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php was only introduced in Magento 1.9.2.2 it sounds to me like you downloaded the patch for version 1.9.2.2 and not for version 1.9.2.1. You should download this patch: magentary.com/wph/contentary/uploads/SUPEE-7405-1.9.2.1.zip

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just checked the zip I downloaded before. Zip File is named 7405-1.9.2.1 and the files seem to be equal to the zip in youre recommended link. I downloaded the Supee 6788 and found the UnserializeArrey.php. It seems the Admin before did not update as he supposed to. I'm not shure if I can just push the 6788 over now.

Comment: My suggestion: backup your Magento folder in its current state, apply patch 6788 and test. If something goes terribly wrong, use your backup folder as restore. Also don't forget to enable the patch 6788 in the backend after applying it.

Comment: Thank you very mutch Digital Pianism!! Need to do some changes for now. Will update the shop later.

Comment: Applying 6788 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have here a list of known bugs after patching Magento : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98236/33619
Some people are trying to fix them