# Can anyone guide on which order I should put security patches 8788, 6285, 6482, 7405, 5344, 6788?

Tags: magento-1.7

I am getting fatal error ie.  Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Helper_UnserializeArray' not found in app/Mage.php

I have referred below 2 links -
i) [Blank admin page after installing SUPEE7405](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98286/blank-admin-page-after-installing-supee7405)
ii) [Blank admin page after installing SUPEE7405 in magen1.9.2.2 and error Fatal error: Class 'Unserialize_Parser'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99120/blank-admin-page-after-installing-supee7405-in-magen1-9-2-2-and-error-fatal-erro)

But that is for version 1.9.2.2.  I want it for magento 1.7.0.1.

Please help me what shall I do to apply security patches. I am trying to find SUPEE-6788 and supee7405 for magento version 1.7.0.1 but not able to get.

I got the link i.e https://github.com/magecomp/Magento-Pre-Patched-Files

Following security patches are not available - 
8788, 6285, 6482, 7405, 5344, 6788.

Can anyone guide on which order I should put above security patches

Comment: i heard `security patches` should be installed in ascending order like 112 , 123, 178 ,245, 789` , also scan your site [here](http://magereport.com/)

Comment: @BabyinMagento....hmm.Thanks  i.e 5344, 6285, 6482,6788, 7405, 8788