# Security Patch SUPEE-7405 or next version?

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-7405

With the new Security Patch SUPEE-7405 and all its linked impacts ([Security Patch SUPEE-7405 - possible problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems)) do you think it is better to apply it on current version or waiting for a new Magento release including it and make an upgrade ?
I know that depends on the current version, the different rewrites, the themes, but I ask it in a general way.

Comment: By the way keep an eye here as we list possible issues after patching: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems/98236#98236

Comment: If you are on 1.9.2.2, updating to 1.9.2.3 is the same as applying the patches. Since you asked in a general way, see possible duplicate for a general answer.

Comment: @DigitalPianism Yes of course my question come precisely from your answer here

Comment: @fschmengler Thanks for your answer and yes that is a duplicate sorry for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 1.9.2.3 has already been released here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

It includes the following patches:

- SUPEE-5344
- SUPEE-5994
- SUPEE-6237
- SUPEE-6285
- SUPEE-6482
- SUPEE-6788
- SUPEE-7616
- **SUPEE-7405**

So it's your choice either to patch or to upgrade to 1.9.2.3.

Comment: My bad didn't see it ! Thanks for the update ;)