# SUPEE 7405 - Hunk #2 Failed at 43

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, patches, supee-7405

Today 2 patches were released for my Magento 1.9.1.0 CE website - SUPEE 7405 and 7616. Installing 7616 on my local dev site worked perfectly and I experienced no problems. When attempting to run 7405 I received the following output:

```
IT1+Liam.McArthur@IT1 MINGW32 /c/xampp/htdocs/website
$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2016-01-20-04-42-03.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 43.
Hunk #3 succeeded at 64 with fuzz 2 (offset -4 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Admin.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/options/type/file.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/creditmemo/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/renderer/default.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals/discount.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
checking file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
checking file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
```

Here's the function it appears to be failing on (line 43) of Observer.php:

```
public function actionPreDispatchAdmin($observer)
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    /** @var $session Mage_Admin_Model_Session */
    $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
    $user = $session->getUser();

    $requestedActionName = $request->getActionName();
    $openActions = array(
        'forgotpassword',
        'resetpassword',
        'resetpasswordpost',
        'logout',
        'refresh' // captcha refresh
    );
```

Is anyone else experiencing problems patching this update or does anybody have any guidance on what could be causing the issue?

**UPDATE**: I've noticed that the following code doesn't exist in app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php. Would this indicate a previous patch has failed?

```
if (!$request->getInternallyForwarded()) {
    $request->setInternallyForwarded();
```

Comment: Did you try the other way around ? Applying 7405 first then 7616 ?

Comment: That wouldn't make a difference. 7616 patches some USPS files and no files relating to the other patch.

Comment: Didn't notice it was CE as well. That's definitely a bug. Feel free to report it to Magento.

Comment: https://twitter.com/piotrekkaminski/status/689928994293047296 Installation failed in new 1.14.2.2 "can you report to support? I haven't seen that issue before. are you sure you are using 1.14.2.2 patch (not some earlier version)?"

Comment: It's the SUPEE-7405 for CE 1.9.1.0-1.9.1.1 patch - as I'm running Magento CE 1.9.1.0.

Comment: Same issue occurred for me (SUPEE-7405 for CE 1.9.1.0-1.9.1.1 patch)

Comment: I think there's mistakes in the .sh file for 1.9.1.0. I'm currently making a live site back up to perform some tests on and will update on here if I find out how to fix it.

Comment: @Zinat take a look at my answer. You may have the same problem that I have where we haven't installed a previous patch, in my case it is SUPEE 5344. If you're getting the exact same error on the same hunk and same line of code, it's probably the same missing patch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the website isn't patched for SUPEE 5344. This means that new code snippets such as `$request->setInternallyForwarded()' don't exist in the Observer.php and are making the line numbering incorrect.

Comment: Hi Nick, How you have installed SUPEE 5344 patch?