# SUPEE 7405 Enterprise Edition Fatal error Undefined class constant 'AREA_ADMINHTML

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.14, supee-7405

After installing supee 7405

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'AREA ADMINHTML in
>   `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php`

It is enterprise edition 1.14

Comment: Could you post the relevant code form app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php that's using the AREAADMINHTML constant?

Comment: Thanks for the response, upgrading PHP version to 5.5 sorted out the issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure to clean all Caches and then (if you have APC or php >= 5.5) restart php service in order to clean opcode cache.

Comment: Done already but not helped :(

Answer (score 1):

Please reach out to Magento support - that way we will help in your case and be able to help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

if i comment line 962 with the
 “$this->_makeEventsLowerCase(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, $mergeModel);” 
 it will turn to the install site http://＊＊＊＊＊＊/index.php/install/ 。

Comment: i update the php version to PHP5.5 and install the patch  again .And everything is ok...