# Following 1.9.2.3 update order view from admin page not working?

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-7405

Is there a fix this or is it expected that a further imminent update will fix. Is it possible to find information on when a fix may be due?

Site not fully usable with this error in place and although I have a backup prior to update I now have fresh orders stacking up which I will need to re-enter manually I presume if I go back to my backup. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is only affecting Magento websites running on PHP < 5.4

The fix can be found here: [Security Patch SUPEE-7405 - possible problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems/98237#98237)

Comment: Thanks for speedy response. As a result my host has been able to update server to PHP v5.4 and problem therefore resolved. Thank you for your help