# How to test SUPEE-7405

Tags: patches

A lot of core files will be patched (~76 CE, ~85 EE). If I take a look at the files I do see a lot of different modules are affected: PayPal, Newsletter, Import/Export, Authorize, Checkout, ...

I can apply the patch successfully on a dev site. But how can I check if it doesn't break anything? Placing an order works - but does it make sense to test all related modules? Or is it safe to push it live?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you keep an eye here as the stackexchange community lists all the known issues after the patch.

This way you can know what to test:

[Security Patch SUPEE-7405 - possible problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/98220/2380)

Comment: Thats awesome! I didn't see this. Thanks.