# Error after installing patch 7405 on Magento 1.4.0.1

Tags: security, patches, supee-7405

The Magento patch 7405 adds a function to `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php` that is as follows:

```
/**
 * Escape string preserving links
 *
 * @param array|string $data
 * @param null|array $allowedTags
 * @return string
 */
public function escapeHtmlWithLinks($data, $allowedTags = null)
{
    if (!empty($data) && is_array($allowedTags) && in_array('a', $allowedTags)) {
        $links = [];
        $i = 1;
        $regexp = "/<a\s[^>]*href\s*?=\s*?([\"\']??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU";
        while (preg_match($regexp, $data, $matches)) {
            //Revert the sprintf escaping
            $url = str_replace('%%', '%', $matches[2]);
            $text = str_replace('%%', '%', $matches[3]);
            //Check for an valid url
            if ($url) {
                $urlScheme = strtolower(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
                if ($urlScheme !== 'http' && $urlScheme !== 'https') {
                    $url = null;
                }
            }
            //Use hash tag as fallback
            if (!$url) {
                $url = '#';
            }
            //Recreate a minimalistic secure a tag
            $links[] = sprintf(
                '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false),
                parent::escapeHtml($text)
            );
            $data = str_replace($matches[0], '%' . $i . '$s', $data);
            ++$i;
        }
        $data = parent::escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
        return vsprintf($data, $links);
    }
    return parent::escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
}
```

However, when trying to view an order, I'm getting a fatal error because the parent class does not have an `escapeHtml()` function. Here's the error:

```
Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract::escapeHtml()
```

It seems the `htmlEscape()` may be what we need, but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 4):

It does seem that changing all instances of `parent::escapeHtml` in the file to `parent::htmlEscape` gets this working.

Comment: Yep, somewhere in Magento 1.4.x.x, escapeHtml was deprecated and renamed to htmlEscape(). When they backported SUPEE-7405, the developers forgot that fact and what works for 1.4.2.0 comes up numpty when applied to 1.4.0.1.

Comment: @FiascoLabs this is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you! Patched that manually. Supee 7405 is the worst Magento Patch ever... Just broke 5.3 compatibility and now this issue... Lets see whats next :)