# Magento 1.9.2.3 Email-Queue not working

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron, supee-7405, queue

After installing the last patch 1.9.2.3 i can't send order notifications. When i run the cron it tries to send the E-Mail but i get the following error.

```
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /xxxxxxx/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:156
Stack trace:
#0 /xxx/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /xxx//lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(241): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#4 /xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(326): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#6 /xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /xxx/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#9 /xxx/cron.php(78): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#10 {main}
```

I have looked around and i know that this is a problem when you don't set the path to sendmail in backend back that is all correct. The mail function is active, too.

If i send an Email not over the queue so directly an forgotten Password its working well. Only the Queue functionality is broken. I have debugged a lot. The function `_sendMail()` in `SendMail.php` is called i write a text to the log files before and after but only the mail function isn't called its very strange.

Anyone an idea or have the same problem with that patch? I have seen in the other thread that there are a lot of problem with the new Patch.

**Update:**

The interesting thing is that my emails are queued in the `core_email_queue` with `processed_at` NULL. When i run the cron the processed date is set but the E-Mail isn't send. In the same Moment i get the error on top.

I have that problem only on my managed server. On my local machine the Email is sent what is very strange and i have no problems and no exception.

Comment: magento_root/cron.su ? Do you not mean magento_root/cron.sh ?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i think that is a provider and sendmail problem. As solution i use an SMTP extension to sind over my STMP server that is working.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem few days ago while I upgraded from magento **1.9.0.1** to **1.9.2.2**, 
After searching from internet, I found that Order Notification process is changed and instead of directly sending email, Magento is making an email queue for email sending. Which will be processed by cron.php later on.

As you mentioned that your mail() function works perfectly, then please take a look at below database table for email queues:

> core_email_queue

If all your order notification mails are stuck there unsent, then you should setup a cron to send those emails.

If your cron is setup correctly, please verify that these 2 files have proper permissions:

> magento_root/cron.php
>
> magento_root/cron.su

Comment: Its not working ;) There are 4 Emails in the queue which aren't send but i can't send them with the cron. Its not working there is an Exception (the on top) and the Email can't be processed.

Comment: I run them over the command line without permission thy aren't working

Comment: Are you sure your mail() function exisits, and its enabled:?

Comment: Yes ;) have you read my question? ;) If its not enabled i coulnd't send other Emails from the system right?