# Security Patch SUPEE-7405 Issues

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, supee-7405

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and just applied this patch. There where two errors

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 166.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 177 (offset -10 lines).
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php.rej
```

and

```
can't find file to patch at input line 2293
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
|index a3cdbc8..8b697b9 100644
|--- app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
|+++ app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
```

The first one I can fix manually myself but the second is trying to access a file which doesn't even exist?

Comment: FYI: The patch should create this file, so it's weird that it complains that it cannot find it.

Comment: Having same issue, any solution to this yet?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara this is an old question for a different patch, please look more carefully before close-voting

Comment: The question is not a duplicate and the correct answer is not stated in the suggested duplicate

Answer (score 9):

You need to apply SUPEE-6788 first :)

Comment: If only there was some way to search for Magento patches based on the affected file. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98921/how-to-find-patch-by-affected-target-files