# SUPEE-7405, issue with app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php

Tags: patches

I am running the patch SUPEE-7405 but I get this error:

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php.rej
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml
```

Anyone else had it?

All previous patches are applied, including 6788. No core edits.

Thank you!

This is the content of `applied.patches.list`:

(You can see the line patching file `app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php`
 from patch `6788`)

```
-e -n 2015-07-08 13:37:06 UTC | SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1 | 7226d88b1eeb07a5fbc4e62be189a5219457cc14 | Mon Jun 22 16:32:26 2015 +0300 | 202596e441..7226d88b1e
patching file app/Mage.php
patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml


-e -n 2015-08-05 08:40:42 UTC | SUPEE-6482 | CE_1.9.2.0 | v1 |  | Tue Jul 14 14:17:04 2015 +0300 |
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 209 (offset -24 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php


-e -n 2015-10-28 14:32:08 UTC | SUPEE-5994 | CE_1.6.0.0 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1.patch
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/messages.phtml
patching file get.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 36 (offset -1 lines).
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php


-e -n 2015-10-28 14:38:29 UTC | SUPEE-6237 | EE_1.14.2.0 | v1 | 8b216c42e2e5d2cb5d8e500fcb6690abede9df52 | Fri Jun 12 13:39:59 2015 +0300 | v1.14.2.0..HEAD
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php


-e -n 2015-10-28 15:21:30 UTC | SUPEE-6788 | CE_1.9.0.1 | v1 | be76c3faa9d26b74a513463408211e9921b09341 | Fri Oct 23 14:59:13 2015 +0300 | ea98922
patching file .htaccess
Hunk #1 succeeded at 175 (offset -32 lines).
patching file .htaccess.sample
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 65 with fuzz 2.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 83 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 173 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 476 (offset 5 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 412 (offset 22 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1165 (offset 55 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 1175 (offset 55 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 1185 (offset 55 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #4 succeeded at 305 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 381 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 389 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 756 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 799 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 830 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #10 succeeded at 840 with fuzz 2 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #11 succeeded at 1025 (offset 1 line).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Soap/Server.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Exception.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file cron.php
patching file errors/processor.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 463 with fuzz 2.
patching file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php


-e -n 2016-01-25 16:53:41 UTC | SUPEE-7616 | CE_1.9.2.2-CE_1.8.0.0 | v1 | 1609c0d0be86473d357346fa51f93c12b365d7a1 | Tue Dec 8 12:53:31 2015 +0200 | e1fc3c59c9587427b8a9c88655715f27afbfe970..1609c0d0be86473d357346fa51f93c12b365d7a1
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php
```

Comment: Finally what i did was deleted that file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php and let the patch SUPEE-7405 create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely  SUPE-6788 was not installed properly. Because this file was not shipped with Magento core in the versions prior to Magento 1.9.2.X versions

app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php

Refer [this link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/magento-1-6-2-0-SUPEE-7405-failing/td-p/26811) for more information.

Comment: thanks for the link. this is really weird because we keep a strict control on patches and I'm 100% that i got in the terminal patch applied successfully. Even in applied.patches.list there is a line "patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php" from SUPEE-6788.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer here:
[Security Patch SUPEE-7405 Issues](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98757/security-patch-supee-7405-issues)

Apply SUPEE-6788 first.