# Security Patch SUPEE-7405, issue with api/v2_soap/?wsdl

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-7405

I get the following error when going to `api/v2_soap/?wsdl`:

```
Argument 2 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Config::_makeEventsLowerCase() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Config_Base, instance of Mage_Api_Model_Wsdl_Config_Base given, called in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 960 and defined  in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1647
```

This happened after I applied the 7405 patch. Any ideas how to solve it?

I know about [Security Patch SUPEE-7405 - possible problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems) but this question and answers are about listing issues or testing after the patch, not about solving them.

Comment: This is a known issue already listed here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems/98236#98236 no fix have been released yet.

Comment: Also I've created a bug on Magento that can be tracked here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/1265

Comment: @DigitalPianism don't really care but that question is against everything a good question is on SE. Is it even a question? We should have every separate issue in different questions with different possible answers. I doubt anyone can figure anything from that question and I doubt that I will receive an answer to my problem on that question.

Comment: I also experienced this issue.
To stop the message from being displayed I simply set MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE to false & display_errors to 0 within index.php - It's not a permanent solution but it allows you to use wsdl in the interim of Magento resolving the issue.

Answer (score 16):

**23rd February 2016 Edit**

Magento has released a v1.1 of the patch that addresses that particular issue, I've updated the hacky fix below so it reflects the official fix but I suggest you apply the v1.1 of the patch SUPEE-7405 to fix that issue.

**25th January 2016 Bug fix**

After digging into the bug, I've made a hacky fix for this particular issue:

Copy the `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php` and in the `_makeEventsLowerCase` function declaration, replace the following code:

```
protected function _makeEventsLowerCase($area, Mage_Core_Model_Config_Base $mergeModel)
```

With this one:

```
protected function _makeEventsLowerCase($area, Varien_Simplexml_Config $mergeModel)
```

You can use that while Magento is working on a fix.

Comment: You can also adjust the type hint in the method Mage_Core_Model_Config::_makeEventsLowerCase from Mage_Core_Model_Config_Base to its base class Varien_Simplexml_Config.

Comment: Yes I thought about doing this but as API XML files do not contain any event, I thought it would be useless

Comment: Thank you, this hotfix solved my problem of v2_soap?wsdl url throwing a white screen (no apache errors only 200 response for some strange reason just blank page) but recommended to COPY app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php so as not to break patching functionality in the future and apply this hotfix on app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php

Comment: Yeah you're right totally forgot to specify that ;)

Comment: @AadMathijssen congrats you had the official fix ;)