# supee 7405 Hunk #2 FAILED at 472. Magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.8, patches, supee-7405

I am trying to install this via shell, but this supee 7405 is giving me a problem.

Originally line 82 was failing too, (failed at line ending)
So I removed the \r line endings in notpad++

The only error I get now is:

`app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php Hunk #2 FAILED at 472. 1 out of 2 hunks FAILED`

As a workaround, I tried uploading the patched file, and then running the patch to update the rest of the files, but it still does not work..

No one else seems to have this issue with this file. All previous patches are applied

Any ideas please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you modified that file. Magento patches require original files. Try to obtain the original file for that version of magento, replace for the one you have now (Backup first), and run the patch installer again.

Comment: OK thanks I will try that. The modified date in the file, matches the installation though but we will see

Comment: That did it, it turned out that for some reason line 485 was like this -   $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*checkout/cart*'));                   instead of like                                                                                        $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed SUPEE-6285 as a prerequisite.

Check app/etc/applied.patches.list and apply ALL missing previous security patches in the order in which they were released.

Hunk failures are caused by code mismatches from

1. Modified core files
2. Core files that got corrupted on upload (added spaces, line ending translation failure, etc.)
3. missing previous patches.

All the above cause file content mismatch when `patch` attempts to find the expected original content and refresh it to the new content. This mismatch is known as a hunk failure.