# After Security patch supee-7405 topmenu is not displaying

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, supee-7405

I have install supee-7405 patch after than topmenu is not displaying in frontend because menu block dont have permission than when i add new premission for block gives this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `setData()` on a non-object in `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php` on line 113

How to solve this problem

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems?rq=1 check this..

Comment: That's an interesting bug. Do you have applied the previous patches ? Could try logging out, deleting your var/session files and flushing your browser cookies before trying again ?

Comment: @DigitalPianism yes i applied the previous patches and try all the thing but it gives same error

Comment: Hmm that's interesting, are you use a superadmin user or a restricted user ?

Comment: restricted user

Comment: Do you have the following line in your `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml` file : `<block type="adminhtml/permissions_block_edit" name="adminhtml.permissions.block.edit"/>` (it should be under the `<adminhtml_permissions_block_edit>` handle)