# Problem in uploading catalog images after upgrade to Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: catalog, product-images, image-upload, ce-1.9.2.3

I upgraded to magento 1.9.2.3 and now, when I try to upload a product image, the back-end shows the white square with a "?" in the centre. I attach a screenshot. Can you help me to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I don't find a solution in that topic.

Comment: Check for the permissions on the files, if they are 640 and 777 solves your problem then the problem is in the patch.

Comment: Except that I don't get the ?", I am experiencing the issue on 1.9.2.3 and changing to 777 did not help.  After rollover the screen shows a image entry row but no image. If I try again it adds another empty row.

Comment: I changed the folder to 777 and it didn't work. You must have been talking about Liam's answer in that link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less than a full answer but i looked thru the link Fabian put in comments and found an answer that I tried and it worked.
[Liam's answer link with comments](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems/99124#99124)

```
Here's a problem I've found when patching Magento CE with SUPEE-7405. It replaces the line:

chmod($destinationFile, 0777);

with:

chmod($destinationFile, 0640);

in the file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

This stopped my images displaying in the back end, since this file permission should actually be 644. Is there any reason this has been set to 640?
```

When I changed the line 219 to 0777 from 0640 it worked.
Until I have a better understanding I'll use this.