# Security Patch SUPEE-7405 Error

Tags: magento-1.7, supee-7405

After installing the security patch SUPEE-7405 I have got the following error in the backend:
`Mage registry key "_singleton/Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy" already exists`

I tried to clear the cache, but no change.

Does someone know how to fix this?

**EDIT:** As a workaround I did the following:

```
   if(isset(self::$_registry["_singleton/Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy"])) {
        self::unregister("_singleton/Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy");
    }
```

in the `Mage.php`. This works for the moment, but does anyone know how to find out in which files the key is setted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-7405 - possible problems?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems)

Comment: Turn off and clear the compiler.

Comment: I already did, but no change. The error still appears.

Comment: Which version are you using ?

Comment: I am using Magento 1.7.0.0 and followed this guide https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-supee-7405-with-or-without-ssh/.

For the patch: https://magecomp.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/MC_SUPEE_7405_Magento_1.7.0.2.zip

Comment: Also did you apply previous patches ?

Comment: Yes, I added all previous patches. So I do not know what went wrong.