# Magento Admin thrown error after applying SUPEE 7405 security patch

Tags: admin, magento-1, fatal-error, supee-7405

When i open admin url, I see this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `getUsername()` on a non-object
>   in `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/header.phtml` on
>   line 33 Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

if you use customer session than add session condition

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if($session->isLoggedIn()) {

}
```

Comment: can you please share header.phtml filde code here?