# what version of php is recommended magento 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, php

What version of php is recommended with magento 1.9.1.1?

I was running PHP 5.3.29, and ran into problem of **Sales>Orders>Order View Information** were not getting displayed in admin after the latest `SUPEE-7405`!  So I upgraded the PHP version to 5.4.45, and it started to display **Sales>Orders>Order View Information** again.

My cPanel has 5.5.32 and 5.6.18 also available. Is it recommended to upgrade to any of them or not?

Comment: Please refer this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. The difference between 5.3 and 5.6 (and also between 5.4 and 5.6), from the performance point of view is significant and PHP 5.6 is stable enough to relay on.

The upgrade is safe for Magento, Magento is declared to work with 5.6.x. You should not see any problem. If you can do it safely you are encourgaed to do it.

Of course you will also have security and stability benefits with a newer version.

Anyway, AFAIK 5.5 should be the recommended one for Magento 1.9. Upgrading do 5.6 is up to you and it should work without problems.

Comment: Is it recommended to upgrade it to 5.6.x?

Comment: As far as I know 5.5 is the recommended one with 1.9.x, but 5.6 should work as well with some minor improvement.