# Patch SUPEE-7405 v1.1 release, is it same as we had 7405 earlier?

Tags: patches, supee-7405

It's not been long since I had applied `SUPEE-7405` and magento says there is another one available. I am not sure if this is the same as before.

> Today, we are distributing updates that improve our most recent
>   security release. SUPEE-7405 v1.1, Enterprise Edition 1.14.2.4, and
>   Community Edition 1.9.2.4 add support for PHP 5.3 and address issues
>   with upload file permissions, merging carts, and SOAP APIs experienced
>   with the original release. They DO NOT address any new security
>   issues.

What interest me is what does this mean?

**They DO NOT address any new security issues.**

I am sure I am not upgrading at this moment, but what's the main reason of this patch?

What files should I look in to? I have got lot of extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**   No, it's not the same. It patches v1.0 to not break stuff

---

If you had no issues with applying SUPEE-7405 causing any of the following issues, you are probably OK.

1. You go to the Sales Order grid, select a Sales Order to view and the [page comes up blank](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98237/553).
2. Images uploaded for wysiwyg, categories, etc [do not show until the file permissions are changed to 644](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/99124/553)
3. Attempting to use the SOAP API causes the server to throw a 500 error or other nonsense.

Full description of various issues raised by this patch => [Security Patch SUPEE-7405 - Possible Problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems)

**NOTE: SUPEE-7405 v1.1** is a patch of a patch and therefore v1.0 is a prerequisite before installing v1.1. From the release:

> You must install the SUPEE-7405 v 1.0 patch before installing the SUPEE-7405 v 1.1  patch bundle if you are running a version of Magento Enterprise Edition prior to 1.14.2.3 or Magento Community Edition prior to 1.9.2.3

**NOTE:** If you modified the files patched by **v1.0** to restore function to your website, you will have to undo your core modifications before this patch will install. It expects all files modified by **v1.0** to be intact before it will apply.