# Uploaded images in backend 404

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

Uploading images into my backend for a certain item now 404, it seems the permissions set for them are 0640 instead of 0644? Has an update broken this aswell?

Edit: They only 404 in the Backend, the store view is fine. Also noticed new images uploaded give permission 0666 instead of the usual 0644.

Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is when you installed SUPEE 7405, it modified all permission within the site to be able to prevent some security breach.

This was known issue, and now magento has issued a new patch:

You will need to install one more patch to your site.

> Today, we are distributing updates that improve our most recent
>   security release. SUPEE-7405 v1.1, Enterprise Edition 1.14.2.4, and
>   Community Edition 1.9.2.4 add support for PHP 5.3 and address issues
>   with upload file permissions, merging carts, and SOAP APIs experienced
>   with the original release. They DO NOT address any new security
>   issues.

**NOTE: SUPEE-7405 v1.1 is a patch of a patch and therefore v1.0 is a prerequisite before installing v1.1. From the release:**

> You must install the SUPEE-7405 v 1.0 patch before installing the
>   SUPEE-7405 v 1.1 patch bundle if you are running a version of Magento
>   Enterprise Edition prior to 1.14.2.3 or Magento Community Edition
>   prior to 1.9.2.3

[You can also check this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103133/patch-supee-7405-v1-1-release-is-it-same-as-we-had-7405-earlier)

Comment: Cool cool! Thanks for quick reply. Answered.