# Problema with 640 permission in uploaded files - Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: product, products, image-upload, varien-file-uploader

When I do upload product images, these images are given 640 permission and do not appear in the backend. When I run `magento-cleanup.php`, everything back to normal and the pictures are shown.

> How to set default permission **644** of all theses images uploaded?

In the temp directory **/media/temp/** and **/media/catalog/product/**, all images are 640 permission after upload.

Magento 1.9.2.3

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a SUPEE-7405 v1.0 issue, apply the re-release, this patch => SUPEE 7405 v1.1 in order to take care of the permissions issue

[Patch SUPEE-7405 v1.1 release, is it same as we had 7405 earlier?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103133/patch-supee-7405-v1-1-release-is-it-same-as-we-had-7405-earlier)