# Updated version of patch SUPEE-7405 V.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-7405

Yesterday (February 23, 2016) I received a notification about a new Version of the patch SUPEE-7405. At first I was a little confused as I applied this patch back in January.

What is changed in this new version?

As I understand there are **no new security issues** is just to make additional fixes to the security issues that were patch with V1.0. Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So basically, the updated version of the patch fixes some of the issues it brought (see details here: [Security Patch SUPEE-7405 - possible problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems/98236#98236))

> The SUPEE-7405 v 1.1 patch bundle includes the following:
>
> **Cart Merge Patch (SUPEE-7978)**
>
> Carts with identical items now merge correctly. Previously, when a
>   cart with one item was merged with another cart that contained the
>   same item, Magento did not merge the cart totals correctly. The cart
>   now includes only one item, and the total is correct.
>
> **SOAP API Patch (SUPEE-7822)**
>
> The Magento SOAP API now works as expected. Previously after
>   installing the SUPEE-7405 v1.0 patch, an API request would cause a 500
>   error, and Magento would log an exception.
>
> **PHP 5.3 Compatibility (SUPEE-7882)**
>
> The patch was not compatible with PHP 5.3 for earlier versions of
>   Magento that were still supporting this version. Merchants
>   experiencing this issue were unable to view sales information in the
>   Admin.
>
> **Upload File Permissions**
>
> The patch restores less restrictive file permissions (0666 for files
>   and 0777 for directories) as more strict permissions introduced by the
>   original SUPEE-7405 patch caused many merchants not to be able to view
>   uploaded product images, depending on hosting provider configuration.

**Technical Details After Digging Into The Patch**

- The `[]` has been properly replaced with `array()` in `Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Sales` to **fix the PHP < 5.4 backward incompatibility**
- The `_makeEventsLowerCase` function of `Mage_Core_Model_Config` now accepts any `Varien_Simplexml_Config` as second parameter instead of `Mage_Core_Model_Config_Base` to **fix the 500 SOAP API issue.**
- The `Varien_File_Uploader` permissions have been rolled back to 666 for files (640 with patch V1) and 777 for folders (750 with patch V1) to **fix the file upload issues.**
- Even if changes have been made to `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php` to **fix the quote items not merged correctly bug** it seems like it does not fully address the issue. Fabian Schmengler made the following comment about it:

> It still does not fix the issue properly. The problem is, the
>   buyRequest option is compared when checking for equality. Changed
>   session => item treated as different. Remaining problem:
>   `related_products` is an empty array for products added via product page
>   and not present when added via list. Also, any arbitrary user POST
>   data is in the `buyRequest` option, so you can actively prevent merging.
>   Removing `&& !$item->getProduct()->hasCustomOptions()` from the
>   `compare()` method worked great for me so far.

**List of files affected**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

**Important notes**

- Patch v1.1 **does not contain** the changes of Patch v1.0. You need to apply the v1.0 before v1.1.
- Do not forget to rollback the custom changes you made after the v1.0 patch before applying patch v1.1
- Magento 1.9.2.4 includes a modification that is not included in the patch: **adds CURLOPT_SSLVERSION as an allowed parameter in Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl**

**Useful links**

- Patch overview: https://gist.github.com/peterjaap/002705a84fd409cb5c2c
- Fabian Schmengler conversation on Twitter: https://twitter.com/PeterJaap/status/702422344690769920
- List of files modified between 1.9.2.3 and 1.9.2.4: http://cl.ly/fEbd