# Logged-in/Guest customers are failing to log-in or shop after patch SUPEE7405

Tags: patches, supee-7405, magento-1.9.2.1

I am using magento 1.9.2.1.

I was installing the patch SUPEE-7405 to my store in production manually, but I noted that after installing the patch, none of the customers are able to login nor any guest customer were able to shop.

Already a customer when trying to login, redirecting to the same login page without any error.

Also, as a guest customer, unable to move to cart page instead moving to a page with login link.

Also, admin section section "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page".

So, I reverted the patch SUPEE-7405. Reverting this allowed admin to login but already logged-in customer faced the same issue. 
If I cleared the browser cache, then I was able to login.

My concern is that many customers who had opened my store and if do not clear browser cache will not be able to shop.

Can anyone please help me to get out of this issue?

Comment: I guess this will help you to solve your issues - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems

Comment: I am not sure if deleting /var/session/ will solve the issue or not. Or it may broke every customer loose their session, Please let me know!

Comment: deleting /var/session/ will logout all customers/admin if they signed in.

Comment: @Yesha: Also, is there a way with which I can clear customers browser cookie?