# OAuth Authorized Tokens ACL

Tags: magento-1.9, acl

I'm having a problem on a client website, which seems to also occur in a fresh install of Magento.  I've set up a custom role "test", and I tick `OAuth Authorized Tokens`, and hit save.  When I go back to the page, it doesn't stay ticked.  It seems to save the value in `admin_rule`, but it's not reflected in the checkbox on returning to the page.

The issue arose due to some custom code having the same issue.  The developer had added a capital letter into the XML node name for ACL in their system.xml.  Once changed and re-set, these then remained ticked.

Sure enough, I've found that if I change Magento's XML node to `authorizedtokens` instead of `authorizedTokens`, it saves and restores the setting correctly.

Is this a bug?  It's an annoying one, as I'm not sure the client is actually likely to usee this feature, but they've pointed it out.  Seems daft to have to rewrite a couple of classes and update the ACL XML node to get this to work.

Comment: Is that 2.0.6? It had some changes in the files reg. OAuth IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

If it's reproducible in a vanilla Magento environment, then you should [report it as a bug](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/bug-tracking/search/results/) with Magento.

Looking at the code `app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Block/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizedTokens/Grid.php` references the ACL path `system/oauth/authorizedTokens` as you suggested. That being said, the `adminhtml.xml` in that module also defines it in the same case which should mean there's no issue.

When I search for `authorizedtokens` (case sensitive) I get nothing over my core code.

One thing you may consider however is that one of the more recent Magento security patches addressed an issue with casing in configuration and module path names - it may be worth [investigating SUPEE-7405](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems) if you haven't installed it already.