# Magento CE 1.9.0.1 double login and redirects back to login

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login, nginx

When I go to the admin, Magento request the user and password as it normally should but after I enter my credentials and send I am seeing this:

[image]

If I enter anything in there I go back to the normal login page, any ideas?

**TRIED ALREADY**

- Deleted var/session and var/cache
- Changed session backend to DB in local.xml
- skin/adminhtml/default/default/css folder is untouched (I compared it to stack code)

**CONTEXT**

The site has been suffering from a series of attacks because of this [AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00JLUV1ZI?qid=1470704226886&sr=0-9&ref_=srh_res_product_title) 
and after the incidents, I decided to restore snapshot and install all security patches by myself and I ended up not being able to access admin portal by the described behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by reverting security patch [7405](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-7405) by trial and error reverting every security patch installed. I will still have to install it back taking the [issues mentioned in this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems) into account.