# Import products and customer data programatically

Tags: magento2, product, import, csv, programmatically

I needed to programatically export and import customer data, product data and order details. I've successfully created my exports. I'm having problems with my import.

I need to do this using an external PHP script, which is located at project root.
I need to upload products, customer data, customer addresses from a (separate) CSV file.

How can I do this?

I have the ususal Magento attributes and few custom product attributes.

Please can someone help me out?

Here is what I got so far:

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

$importProduct = getProductImport();

function getProductImport(){

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $file = 'import/products.csv';
    $arrResult = array();
    $headers = false;
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if (empty($handle) === false) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if (!$headers) {
                $headers[] = $data;
            } else {
                $arrResult[] = $data;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }


    foreach( $arrResult as $importProduct ) {
        $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));

        $product->setAttributeSetId($product->getDefaultAttributeSetId());

        $product->setSku($importProduct[0]);
        $product->setName($importProduct[5]); 

        $product->setStockData(
            array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
                'manage_stock' => 1, // manage stock
                'min_sale_qty' => 1, // Shopping Cart Minimum Qty Allowed 
                'max_sale_qty' => 2, // Shopping Cart Maximum Qty Allowed
                'is_in_stock' => 1, // Stock Availability of product
                'qty' => 78
            )
        );
        $product->save();
        echo "Upload simple product id :: ".$product->getId()."<br>";

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: where will you stuck?

Comment: @AmitBera I tried using same export script to do the imports, didn't work. I followed few Magento1 tutorials, but seems like they were unable to make to work with M2. so all and all, I'm stuck at the begining. very much stuck. please help me if you can. even a small pointer to right path is golden to me at this time

Comment: Please share your import script

Comment: @AmitBera here it is, **https://paste.ofcode.org/Mt5mwsAy5YpGU6wwnLZsmb**

Comment: @AmitBera I've updated my question. please look at it and help me if you can