# Order View Display Nothing

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I didn't know hat happen to my magento site but it seems that the order view is not working. What could be the possible reason for this?
Please help me.
[image]

Comment: refer this http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/99774/45103

Comment: you use cdn in your ssite?

Comment: @jigsparmar no I don't have

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an error in PHP

**Magento Mode**

Go to index.php and modify:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

by

```
#if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#}
```

And

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

by

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**PHP Mode**

This always works for me:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

However, this doesn't make PHP to show parse errors - the only way to show those errors is to modify your php.ini with this line:

```
display_errors = on
```

When you see the error go to url referred by @gopal-patel : [magento order view information is blank page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76320/magento-order-view-information-is-blank-page/99774#99774)

Comment: it is a conflict in the module I added. I have to remove the module ang the Order View is Good Again. Thank you for you time in finding solution on my problem.

Comment: Remember vote up if answer help you with your problem :)